# concatenate 2 dataframes with different number of rows for the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have 2 dataframe df1 and df2.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1','a2'],['b1','b2'],['c1','c2']],columns=['HR','RR'],index=[0,0,1])

df1
Out[146]: 
   HR  RR
0  a1  a2
0  b1  b2
1  c1  c2

df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[['1','2'],['1','2'],['1','2'],['1','2'],['1','2']],columns=['ST','SR'],index=[0,0,0,0,1])

df2
Out[147]: 
  ST SR
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
1  1  2
```

How can I concatenate them in order to get result and result2?

```
result = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1','a2',1,2],['b1','b2',1,2],[np.nan,np.nan,1,2],[np.nan,np.nan,1,2],['c1','c2',1,2]],columns=['HR','RR','ST','SR'],index=[0,0,0,0,1])

result
Out[148]: 
    HR   RR  ST  SR
0   a1   a2   1   2
0   b1   b2   1   2
0  NaN  NaN   1   2
0  NaN  NaN   1   2
1   c1   c2   1   2

result2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan,np.nan,1,2],[np.nan,np.nan,1,2],['a1','a2',1,2],['b1','b2',1,2],['c1','c2',1,2]],columns=['HR','RR','ST','SR'],index=[0,0,0,0,1])

result2
Out[148]: 
    HR   RR  ST  SR
0  NaN  NaN   1   2
0  NaN  NaN   1   2
0   a1   a2   1   2
0   b1   b2   1   2
1   c1   c2   1   2
```

Comment: sorry didn't get your comment..

Comment: Sorry, In the dataframe `result` shouldn't one of the indexes where `Hr` and `RR` are `NaN` be 1 instead of zero

Comment: no...because  df2 has 4 rows with index =0 that should be concatenated with the 2 rows with index =0 of df1

Answer (score 0):

Append another level of index denoting the row number per the current index, then outer join:

```
df1.set_index(
    df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), 
    append=True
).join(
    df2.set_index(
        df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), 
        append=True
    ),
    how="outer"
).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

#    HR RR  ST  SR
#0  a1  a2  1   2
#0  b1  b2  1   2
#0  NaN NaN 1   2
#0  NaN NaN 1   2
#1  c1  c2  1   2
```

---

To invert the NaN positions to the top, you might do the following, i.e., invert the two data frames before hand and then invert them back after the join:

```
df1 = df1.iloc[::-1]
df2 = df2.iloc[::-1]
df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).join(
    df2.set_index(df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True),
    how="outer"
).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).iloc[::-1].sort_index()


#    HR  RR  ST SR
#0  NaN NaN   1  2
#0  NaN NaN   1  2
#0   a1  a2   1  2
#0   b1  b2   1  2
#1   c1  c2   1  2
```

Comment: Thank you! if I want to add the NaN at the beginning I would have to invert df1 with df2?

Comment: I don't think inverting df1 with df2 helps. It'll be more difficult as you need to know how many rows there are for each index.

Comment: Added an option.

Comment: it works in the test case, but it doesn't really work with my real dataframes... o_O

Comment: I'll try to elaborate